# How to run a BAT file which needs to ask for password entry

Tags: batch-file

I have a simple script which will connect to Putty and run one .sh file. For connecting to putty , i need to provide username and password. I have hardcoded my username and password in my bat file. How ever i need to know how to update my script in such a way that when i run my bat file, it should ask for password.

Below is my script:

```
start LOCATION\putty.exe -ssh SERVERNAME.server.rbsgrp.ppe -l USERNAME-pw PASSWORD -m \LOCATION\test.txt -t
```

Comment: You should really do a bit of research before posting here; the information you need is quite easy to come by. I recommend bookmarking [SS64's BATCH reference](https://ss64.com/nt/) as a good site for information on the batch language; you'll find that your question can be answered with a little bit of study of the [`SET` command](https://ss64.com/nt/set.html).

Comment: @JeffZeitlin it's actually not possible to enter a *password* in pure batch. the `SET` command can be used to enter a general string, which is in plain view and therefore not suitable for passwords. There are solutions based on Powershell or other languages.

Comment: @DodgyCodeException - and invoking `putty` from the command line and passing the password via the `-pw` parameter isn't going to pass an encrypted string anyway. By your rationale, no program should be able to take credentials from the command line, unless it requires using PowerShell to start it and pass a credential object.

Comment: @DodgyCodeException, there are ways in a batch file to mask the typing of keyboard input.  We have a couple of threads on DosTips about it.  But has Jeff pointed out you will still see the password within the environment itself although with prompting for the password it should only be visible in the environment for a split second.

Comment: What about running PuTTY without `-pw PASSWORD`, just with `-L USERNAME` and all other options? Does PuTTY in this case not automatically ask the user for the password before the SSH session is successfully established?

Comment: @Mofi I tried that, but the SSH session takes password as empty/null and trying to establish connection and getting failed.